# Why is data from useQuery undefined when I start screen?

Tags: react-native, use-effect, use-state, gql

When I start screen, I get data from `useQuery`

And by using `useEffect`, I get data and immediately sort this data.

After sorting data, I put this data to `useState` named flatlistdata.

And I draw screen by using Flatlist with this data.
Flatlist data should be sorted.

So I need to refined data before.

```
  const { data: allFeedData, refetch: allFeedRefetch } = useQuery(SEE_ALL_FEED_ORDER);

  const [flatlistdata, setFlatlistdata] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    allFeedRefetch();
    setFlatlistdata(
      [...allFeedData.seeAllFeedOrder].sort(function (a, b) {
        return b.directFeedNumber - a.directFeedNumber;
      })
    );
  }, []);


  <FlatList
    data={flatlistdata}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
    renderItem={RankRow}
    refreshing={refreshing}
    onRefresh={refresh}
  />
```

However when I click screen, it says `undefined is not an object` which means data is empty.

I think the problem here is that screen is drawn, before sorting data and putting it to useState...?

I need a little hint 
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is an asynchronous operation, so, the `data` variable will always start out as undefined while the network request completes.  There are two possible solutions.

1. In your useEffect, only set your state if `data` is defined. Wrap your setFlatlistData with `if (allFeedData?.length) { ... }`
2. Use the React Query `selection` prop to have Query do the same operation before `allFeedData` gets populated. Check the `select` prop in the docs for useQuery: https://react-query-v2.tanstack.com/reference/useQuery